# how the following formula or any other explicit formula for computing Bernoulli numbers can be derived?

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

how the following formula 
$$B_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}$$
can be derived?
I know how to use the formula but still have not seen any proof for the given formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The recurrence relation 
>   \begin{align*}
> B_n&=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}\qquad n\geq 0\\
> \end{align*}
>
> specifies a variation of the *[Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)* with $B_1=+\frac{1}{2}$ instead of the more common value $B_1=-\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> We therefore start with the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k=\frac{x}{e^x-1}+x=\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* The recurrence relation also gives $B_0=1$ since we use the convention that an empty sum is equal to zero. This is the case for $n=0$ when the upper limit of the sum is less than the lower limit.

Multiplication of (1) by $e^x-1$ gives

\begin{align*}
xe^x&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k\right)\left(e^x-1\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^\infty\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k\geq 0,l\geq 1}}\frac{B_k}{k!}\frac{1}{l!}\right)x^n\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{B_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\right)x^n\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{B_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k+1)!}\right)x^{n+1}\tag{6}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}\right)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\tag{7}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we expand the exponential function $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.
- In (4) we do the Cauchy multiplication of series.
- In (5) we eliminate $l$ by using $l=n-k$.
- In (6) we shift the index $n$ to start with $n=0$.
- In (7) we expand numerator and denominator by $n!$ and introduce the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.

> From (7) and the expansion of the left-hand side of (2) we obtain after division by $x$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparison of the coefficient of $x^n$ gives after multiplication with $n!$ for $n\geq 0$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=B_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

Comment: The only question I have is about the generation function $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k=\frac{x}{e^x-1}+x$ ,because I've seen that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ ,whitout any $+x$ in the right hand side

Comment: @Absurd:  I don't think so. The series expansion of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}x}+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\cdots$.  But  the  recurrence relation  gives  with 
 $B_0=1$:  $B_1=1-\sum_{k=0}^0\binom{1}{k}\frac{B_k}{2-k}=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. This means the series expansion starts with $1\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{2}x}+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\cdots$. This corresponds to $B_1^{+}$ of the referred Wiki page.

Comment: true,but what about the others $B_n$s? how do we know the coefficient won't change like how did for $B_1$.

Comment: @Absurd: This is in fact an outcome of the proof. We make an *Ansatz* with $xe^x/(e^x-1)$ and the proof shows, we actually get the wanted recurrence relation showing that all the other $B_n$'s are the same.

Comment: and if we add $x^2$ instead of $x$ then we should expect a coefficient change for $B_2$?

Comment: @Absurd: Correct. We then would have $1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{7}{6}x^2+\cdots$ giving the sequence $(1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{6},\ldots)$ and the generating function $x/(e^x-1)+x^2$.

Comment: and you just add a $x$ to get the desired formula? or does this have any other reason?

Comment: @Absurd: Correct.  Since we have $B_1=1/2$ and the generating function for the Bernoulli numbers is well known, I've simply added $x$ to $x/(e^x-1)$. This makes the shift from $B_n^{-}$ to $B_n^{+}$ as they are named at the Wiki page.

Comment: @Absurd: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is immediate from the definition $$\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k$$ which means $$1=\frac{e^x-1}{x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k = ( \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+1)!} x^m)( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{B_k}{k!}\frac1{ (n-k+1)!}) x^n$$
ie. $$B_0=1, \qquad  for \ n > 1\ \qquad \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{B_k}{k! (n-k+1)!} = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me how your formula gives us the Nth Bernoulli number?

Comment: Don't you see the relation between my formula and yours ?

Answer (score 1):

The following [formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145271?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
 has been proved in The American Mathematical Monthly, but here the proof is deeper and doesn't use any induction:

consider the function $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{e^{x}+1}=\frac{e^{x}+1-2}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}-\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{e^{x}+1}-\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$$

Using the famous definition of Bernoulli numbers we have:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{∞}B_{n}\ \frac{x^{n}}{n!}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{∞}B_{n}\ \frac{2^{n}x^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{∞}B_{n}\ \frac{x^{n-1}}{\left(n\right)!}\left(1-2^{n}\right)$$

let $n-1↦n$, implies:$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{∞}B_{n+1}\ \frac{x^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(1-2^{n+1}\right)$$

Computing $$f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)$$ gives the following relation:
(**I**)
$$f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)=\frac{B_{n+1}\left(1-2^{n+1}\right)}{n+1}$$

On the other hand from the answer of [user90369](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416127/general-formula-for-the-nth-derivative-of-fx-frac11ex) we can compute the $n^{th}$ derivative of $$ \frac{1}{e^{x}+1}$$ around $x=0$ which is as follows:

(**II**) $$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\frac{1}{e^{x}+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}{{k}\choose{j}}\left(j+1\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$

comparing the $n^{th}$  derivative of the function from **I** and **II** we arrive at the explicit formula for the $n+1^{th}$ Bernoulli number:

$$B_{n+1}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(n+1\right)}{2^{\left(n+1\right)}-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{\left(k\right)}}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{j}\left(j+1\right)^{n}{{k-1}\choose{j}}$$ which is valid for $n\ge0$.