# general formula for the nth derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}$

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

consider the function :$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}$$

the nth derivative of the function is given by the following formula:

$$f^{(n)} (x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_{n,k}\frac{1}{\left(1+e^{x}\right)^{k}}$$ where

$$a_{n,k}=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{j}{{k-1}\choose{j}}\left(j+1\right)^{n}$$

my question is that:how the formula can be derived without using induction? I have no idea about that, so any hint or full proof would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use induction!

Comment: I haven't done the computation, but I'd try induction

Comment: @Lucas Smits, I know I can do it, but where does the formula come from? the first person who introduced the formula did not use induction to create it and had an idea for deriving that!

Comment: @ajotatxe do you know any other way except induction?

Comment: The person who came up with the formula probably wrote out the derivative for n = 1, 2, 3, ... and saw a pattern. With that pattern, you can "guess" a formula and then prove its correctness with induction.

Comment: @slimmerikko the problem is that I cannot find the full pattern.

Comment: This seems to be an application of the *general Lebniz rule*, which is basically a generalisation of the product rule ( Also known as Lebniz rule).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#Proof

Comment: Note that the proof by Wikipedia also uses induction

Comment: @ ONG SEE HAI HCI, I think so,but do we have both $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Note that $$f'(x) = -f(x) + f(x)^2,$$ and $$[f(x)^n]' = nf'(x) f(x)^{n - 1} = n\Big(f(x)^{n + 1} - f(x)^n\Big).$$ You can now derive $f$ many times and see the pattern. (noticing $f^{(n)} $ is a polynomial in $f(x)$ with degree $n + 1$ and constant term zero might also help.)

Comment: Writing $f^{(n)} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1} a_{n,j} f(x)^j$ and using the identity above can atleast change the problem to the following recurrence relations $$a_{n+1,n+2} = a_{n,n+1} (n+1)$$ 
$$a_{n+1,j} = (j - 1)a_{n,j-1} - a_{n,j},\quad 1 \leq j \leq n+1.$$
But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: This might help: $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}(-k)^ne^{-kx}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A calculation *without recurrence relation* and *without induction*.

Let’s use the following formula, both sides come from the mixed bivariate generating function $~\displaystyle e^{z(e^x-1)}~$ for the Stirling numbers of the second kind:

> $$e^{-z}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}k^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n z^k S(n,k)$$

$S(n,k)~$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) .

Setting $~z:=at~$, multiplicating by $~e^{-t}~$ and integrating from $~t=0~$ to $~\infty~$ we get:

> $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k^n\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^k = (a+1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k k!S(n,k)$$

Setting $~\displaystyle\frac{a}{1+a} = -e^{-x}~$, substracting $~S_{n,0}=0^n~$ and

using $~S(n+1,k+1)=(k+1)S(n,k+1)+S(n,k)~$ we get:

> $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n\left(-e^{-x}\right)^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1} k!S(n+1,k+1)}{(1+e^x)^{k+1}}$$

It follows:

$\hspace{1cm}~\displaystyle\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1+e^x} = (-1)^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n\left(-e^{-x}\right)^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{a_{n,k+1}}{(1+e^x)^{k+1}}~$

with $~~~\displaystyle a_{n,k+1} = (-1)^{n+k} k!S(n+1,k+1) = \left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}{{k}\choose{j}}\left(j+1\right)^{n}$

---

*Notes:*

$\displaystyle e^{z(e^x-1)}=e^{-z}e^{ze^x}=e^{-z}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}e^{xk}=e^{-z}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n k^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n }{n!}\left(e^{-z}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k k^n}{k!}\right)$

$\displaystyle e^{z(e^x-1)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}(e^x-1)^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}{\binom k j}e^{xj}=$

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.5cm}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}{\binom k j}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}j^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}{\binom k j}j^n\right)$

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.5cm}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty z^k S(n,k)\right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n z^k S(n,k)\right)$

$\hspace{1.8cm}$ because of $~S(n,k)=0~$ for $~k>n$

Comparing the coefficients of $~x^n~$ we get the first formula.

And the second formula comes from integrating by $~\int\limits_0^\infty ... dt~$ ;

with $~c>0~$ it's $\displaystyle~\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^{ct}}dt=\frac{1}{c^{n+1}}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{(ct)^n}{e^{ct}}d(ct)=\frac{n!}{c^{n+1}}~$ :

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(at)^k}{e^{at}k!}k^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (at)^k S(n,k) ~~~~ |\cdot e^{-t} ~~~~ |\int\limits_0^\infty ... dt$

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k k^n}{k!}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{t^k}{e^{(a+1)t}}dt = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k S(n,k)\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{t^k}{e^t}dt$

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k k^n}{(1+a)^{k+1}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k k!S(n,k) ~~~~ |\cdot (1+a)$

From there to the third formula:

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k^n\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^k = (a+1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k k!S(n,k)$

$\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^{k+1} k!S(n,k) + \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k k!S(n,k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a^k (k -1)!S(n,k-1) + \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a^k k!S(n,k) $

$\displaystyle = a^{n+1} n!S(n,n) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a^k (k -1)!(S(n,k-1) + k S(n,k)) + a^0 0!S(n,0) $

$\displaystyle = a^{n+1} n!S(n,n) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a^k (k -1)!S(n+1,k) + S(n,0) $

$\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a^k (k -1)!S(n+1,k) + S(n,0) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a^{k+1} k!S(n+1,k+1) + S(n,0) $

Substracting $~0^n=S(n,0)~$ leads to $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a^{k+1} k!S(n+1,k+1)~$ .

With setting $\displaystyle ~\frac{a}{1+a}=-e^{-x}~$ we get $\displaystyle ~a=-\frac{1}{1+e^x}~$ and therefore the last formula.

Comment: I'm sure that your answer is great (I give +1),but I did not think that my question to be advanced that much, do you have any reference(s) which proves your used formulas?

Comment: @Absurd: Thanks! E.g. the *second formula* you can see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html),  line $(29)+(30)$ . I've added the mixed bivariate generating function for the Stirling numbers of the second kind, which produces the *first formula*. So, you know how it's possible to start. ;)

Comment: @Absurd : I everything understandable now or should I show how to get the first formula from $~e^{z(e^x-1)}~$ ?

Comment: If you do that,I will appreciate it so much

Comment: @Absurd : I've added some notes. ;)

Comment: I got it,is it possible for you to explain the last yellow box too?thnks :)

Comment: @Absurd : Yes, I've added. :) --- But: My answer depends on the *Stirling numbers of the second kind* and of course I don't know if this is o.k. for you; maybe you have specifications which exclude that.

Comment: thnk you again,now I know where do the first and last parts come from,but still I have a problem in second part,could you please explain that with more details?(I'm sorry for that!)

Comment: @Absurd: So, I hope, it's o.k. now. Or any question left ? :)

Comment: now the only problem is when you say :as follows: and you take the derivative,I just have a problem there :)

Comment: @Absurd: Sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean ?

Comment: how do you take the nth derivative of $1/e^x +1$ using your formulas?

Comment: @Absurd: The $~n^{th}~$ derivation of $~\frac{1}{1+e^x}~$ is equivalent to the $~n^{th}~$ derivation of it's series $~-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-e^{-x})^k~$ . You know $~\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k~$ ?

Comment: yes,but how did you use that?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1+e^x} = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-e^{-x})^k\right) = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-xk} = (-1)^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n (-e^{-x})^k ~$ and for $~\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^n (-e^{-x})^k ~$ see the $3^{rd}$ formula.

Comment: should not it be $(-1)^{k+1}$?

Comment: The missed $-1$ is together with $(-1)^n$ of the derivation. If you write $~(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(-1)^k~$ or $~(-1)^n\cdot(-1)^{k+1}~$ has no meaning.

Comment: thnks, how did you use geometric series for the series of $1/1+e^x$?

Comment: It's not clear for me what you like to know. It's $\displaystyle~\frac{1}{1+e^x}=-\frac{(-e^{-x})}{1-(-e^{-x})}=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-e^{-x})^k~$ . ;)

Comment: that's totally true,but don't we have any convergence problem? because I think the formula is not valid for all real $x$(even if we use geometric series which is $1/1+x$,we just can use this for $x$ which are greater than $-1$ and less than $1$.

Comment: A good question. You know the analytic continuation? E.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). If one continues a function (here: the series) analytically in two different ways, for example through functions, then these two functions have the same value range within the intersection of their definition sets. In your case, the common definition range is $\mathbb{R}$. But for comparing the coefficients you don't need that, because they are independend of $x$ . You can also use $x>0$ or whatever is senseful.

Comment: Any question left ? :)

Comment: I guess no,the first time you gave me this answer of my question I was like "this is so hard,I never would be able to understand it",but you made it possible for me,Thank you for all of your answers .

Comment: @Absurd: You are welcome, it was a pleasure. :)